# At boot I enter Recovery Mode; after CTRL+D I can enter normally

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upstart, recovery-mode

I'm used to working on Ubuntu for a year now, but a little over a week ago, grub started acting kind of weird. I did some research and I still cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong.

**Note:** I do realize there might be a few topics about this exact problem and yet, there was none that helped me out.

**Note 2:** I am using a dual-boot with Windows 10

**What happens:**
When I select the standard 'Ubuntu' option, somehow I enter recovery mode. When I exit the recovery mode (by typing `exit`, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), it seems like there is no problem at all and I boot normally into *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*.
Now, when I choose the 'upstart' option, there seems to be no problem whatsoever.

I was wondering whether there was a way to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance,

***Red***

---

**fragment from `journalctl`:**

```
...
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-sda8.device: Job dev-sda8.device/start timed out.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-sda8.device.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap Partition.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-sda8.swap: Job dev-sda8.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-sda8.device: Job dev-sda8.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.device/start time
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.device.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/ca1ce3ca-db6f-4d3a-b4ff-e64c8cd8cf2d.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Swap.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.swap: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.swap/start failed w
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ca1ce3ca\x2ddb6f\x2d4d3a\x2db4ff\x2de64c8cd8cf2d.device/start fail
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.device/start timed out.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.device.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dns-clean.service: Job dns-clean.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Job boot-efi.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/C050-F3AE.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 26 13:51:18 red-X555LJ systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-C050\x2dF3AE.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
...
```

**`etc/default/grub`:**

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="enforcing=0"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

**`sudo blkid`:**

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="C050-F3AE" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="74fa2d57-0a26-472d-b104-e5ed480ce8db"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="482EBC832EBC6C16" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f3aac7a5-0dd1-4546-89a0-922a0cfcc74f"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c85094cf-240a-43d9-a3bc-959226b1c90c"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="OS" UUID="924CC2464CC22537" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="b51d84d1-fa0a-402b-91f2-2877570226fd"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="Data" UUID="5A14C61214C5F155" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5643d736-6840-4e95-b872-e9b3c3406454"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Restore" UUID="44A4CB28A4CB1AF6" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="bed55436-92b8-4ce4-8a6e-12345fa8e4a6"
/dev/sda7: UUID="eb466dde-fa30-433e-95cf-7aeaf423eec3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0239b09c-2aa3-467c-a5c7-0e332b3a551e"
/dev/sda8: UUID="ca1ce3ca-db6f-4d3a-b4ff-e64c8cd8cf2d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="b17e014e-5e2c-4df4-9958-516dd7c8ceb2"
```

**`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`:**

```
RESUME=UUID=ca1ce3ca-db6f-4d3a-b4ff-e64c8cd8cf2d
```

**`/etc/fstab`:**

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=eb466dde-fa30-433e-95cf-7aeaf423eec3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=C050-F3AE  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=ca1ce3ca-db6f-4d3a-b4ff-e64c8cd8cf2d none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=C050-F3AE  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

Comment: This is still a problem and it's bugging me as hell...